# An automatic file history and backup for a word processor

Tags: java, file, history, word-processor, backups

I'm currently making a word processor in Java and one the functions it should have is a file backup and history.

I want to be able to backup text to a text file if the program crashes and display a history of recently opened text files.

I've tried to research the problem but I couldn't find anything useful.
Could someone point me the right direction so I can try and figure this out.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Did you have trouble saving a backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just regularly save a backup of the current editing state to some backup file, the greater the interval the more work you loose on crash.

And for history, just save the recently opened files in some configuration file.

Comment: I suppose that works for backups. I've already got an auto save but it asks you if you want to save if you haven't saved the file yet but I guess I could save a backup somewhere if they say no.

I'll look into that for the history. Thanks

Comment: If this answer was satisfactory for you, please accept it